# How to get .EXE file from TwinCAT XAE project to run on TwinCAT XAR

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, xar

I hope this message finds you well. I have worked on TwinCAT XAE for past couple of months. I have developed and tested my programs on my Development PC using TwinCAT XAE and Visual studio.

Now I want to shift my programs from my development PC to my Runtime PC (Windows) which is eventually going to be installed by the machine. I want some guidance regarding transfering my programs from XAE to XAR. In simple words I want to know how to get the .EXE file to run on the TwinCAT XAR.

I am also facing some configuration issues with XAR. Can you share any installation guide or prerequisites for the TwinCAT XAR software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) make an .EXE file for your target platform (XAR).

.EXE files are run in Windows User Mode and is thus not Real-Time or deterministic.
TwinCAT code needs to be run in Kernel mode to ensure Real-Time and deterministic behavior.

Instead you should connect to your target through Visual Studio. You can change from  to your target platform by pressing on Local and pressing Choose Target System [image: Seen here.]

[Here is a bit of information about how this works.](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsystemmanager/basics/tcsysmgr_choosetargetsystem.htm&id=)

Afterwards you simply Activate the configuration and your code will run on the target platform.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. It cleared my confusion. I want to know if I can use an other system(run time pc) with Windows 10 OS which has TwinCAT XAR installed in it as a remote system. In other words can I select it as a target. Do we need any extra settings to make it work or it will work just like any other hardware controller?

Comment: It should work if TwinCAT XAR is installed. Keep in mind that to guarantee true real-time performance you need to use a Beckhoff machine as they have changed stuff to deliver real-time performance.

Comment: I am using another windows-PC as a Runtime PC. I followed the select Target method. The target system is available by Broadcast search. But, I am unable to connect to it because remote user credentials are unavailable. I have tried the system password and also the default value "1". Can you you guide me on How can I get the password for the Remote User Credentials in TwinCAT 3 XAE. I have already done the TCP and UDP settings in the runtime PC.